# VSTO workbook takes 30 seconds to open

Tags: vsto

This is my first vsto workbook (not add-in).  On my dev machine when launched from VS2017 it takes about 8 seconds to launch excel and load the workbook.  However once I deploy the workbook via clickonce to a network drive (even if I disable 'check for updates') it takes about 30 seconds to open the same workbook.

This can't be correct behavior so I am wondering how to debug this?  There are no errors and everything seems to work correctly, but why is this taking so long?  The xlsm workbook is copied locally and there is no need to check the network AFAIK because updates are disabled.  Loading excel on it's own takes about 3 seconds on my machine so what is happening for the other 27+ seconds?

The workbook itself is dead simple, one blank sheet and then a simple form with a combobox, a couple of buttons and a EF context that populates the combobox and removes rows when you click a button (so far).  This shouldn't take 27+ seconds to load.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2012/05/18/resolving-performance-issues-with-loading-office-add-ins-vsto-add-ins-or-shared-add-ins/

Comment: Very strange.  I tried the suggestion to set generatePublisherEvidence to false.  No change after re-install.  Then I had to un-install the vsto workbook to try profiling which didn't tell me anything I didn't already know (running it from visual studio wasn't the problem).  After a second re-install the problem magically disappeared.  No code changes, nothing.  Simply one config change followed by re-install, uninstall, profile, re-install.  Can't explain it.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: There could be updates pending causing slow load times for excel, reboot machine to apply updates and fix load time issue.

Okay this is particular to my environment but perhaps others have this happen to them and could benefit from my discovery.  So in my company they push updates to machines from a central management service.  Most people get a notification telling them to reboot their machines when updates have been installed, however for people in IT they disable this notification because when you remote log-in to a machine that has this notification present, the machine reboots automatically before you can sign in and there is no way around this behavior (so say the IT guys).  Since IT guys frequently have a million windows open, they did not want their machines rebooting when they remote signed in (which is usually when there is a problem that needs immediate attention) so they disable this notification for all members of IT (which includes me).  I had a pending update I was not aware of and rebooting my machine applied the updates and fixed the issue, which is why it seemed like 'magic' that the problem fixed itself without code changes.  I had rebooted after my last re-install since I had updated itunes and it required a reboot.